# Android bluetooth SDP does not recognize service advertised in JAVAME

Tags: android, service, java-me, bluetooth

I am developing a <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> application for my MSc. End Project. It includes a server implemented in `JAVA ME`, and a client written in `Android`.

The problem  is that Android `SDP` seems to fail at recognizing the `ServiceRecord` of my JAVA ME server.

If I use the methods `BluetoothDevice.getUuids()` and `BluetoothDevice.fetchUuidsWithSdp()` in my client, they return a set of `UUIDs`, but my service's `UUID` is nowhere among them, thus I cannot connect to it.

This is the code for  `JAVAME` server example:

```
/*IMPORTS*/

public class StackOverFlowServer extends MIDlet {
    Display mDisplay;
    Form mForm;
    LocalDevice local;
    StreamConnectionNotifier server;
    ServiceRecord sr;
    String conURL;
    StreamConnection conn;
    public StackOverFlowServer() {
        mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
        mDisplay.setCurrent(mForm);
        mForm = new Form(null);
        conURL = "btspp://localhost:68EE141812D211D78EED00B0D03D76EC;"
                + "authenticate=false;encrypt=false;name=MySampleApp";
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        try {
            local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
            // Error handling code here
        }
        /*
        * When creating a StreamConnectionNotifier a service record
        * will automatically be created for us, describing the new
        * service. The service will have the Serial Port (0x1101)
        * value in the ServiceClassIDList (id 0x0001) attribute. The
        * service record will also have both the L2CAP (0x0100) and
        * RFCOMM (0x0003) values in the ProtocolDescriptorList (id
        * 0x0004) attribute. Other mandatory attributes will be set
        * automatically by the JABWT implementation. The optional
        * ServiceName (id 0x100) attribute will be set to the name
        * parameter, "BTDemoApp" in this case.
        */
        try {
            server = (StreamConnectionNotifier)
                    Connector.open(conURL);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // Error handling code here
        }
        /*
        * The automatically created service record can be obtained
        * from the LocalDevice object, using the reference to the
        * StreamConnectionNotifier.
        */
        try {
            sr = local.getRecord(server);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException iae){
            // Error handling code here
        }
        /*
        * We create a new DataElement and set its content correctly.
        */
        DataElement elm = null;
        /*
        * Setting public browse root in the browsegrouplist
        * attribute. The BrowseGroupList (id 0x0005) attribute
        * contains a DataElement sequence, which in turn contains
        * DataElements with UUIDs. The DataElement sequence must be
        * created before we can add DataElements to it.
        */
        elm = new DataElement(DataElement.DATSEQ);
        elm.addElement(new DataElement(
        DataElement.UUID,new UUID(0x1002)));
        /*
        * The DataElement is now prepared. It must be added to the
        * appropriate attribute ID, in this case the
        * BrowseGroupList.
        */
        sr.setAttributeValue(0x0005,elm);
        /*
        * Finally, the service record must be updated in our
        * LocalDevice.
        */
        try {
            local.updateRecord(sr);
        } catch (ServiceRegistrationException e3) {
            // Error handling code here
        }
        try {
        conn = server.acceptAndOpen();
        } catch (ServiceRegistrationException sre){
            // Error handling code here
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // Error handling code here
        }
        /*
        * At this point a client is connected. input and output
        * streams can be obtained from the conn object,
        * communication can begin.
        */
    }
}
```

And this is part of the Android client:

```
package com.exampleproyect.stackoverflowclient;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class StackOverFlowClientActivity extends Activity {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice C702;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        C702 = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:23:F1:27:16:DA");
        C702.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
              String action = intent.getAction();
              if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)){
                  Parcelable[] uuidExtra =                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
                  /*uuidExtra should contain my service's UUID among his files, but it doesn't!!*/
              }
          }
      };
      // Register the BroadcastReceiver
      IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
      registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
    }
}
```

What bothers me the most, is that my computer can see my `JAVAME` server correctly advertised:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?? :( Why can my PC's <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> see my service correctly advertised in `JAVAME` but Android can't?? Can `Android` connect via <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> to `JAVAME` servers?

I have read tons of other similar questions here  in StackOverFlow but I have not been able to come up with a working solution. :(

I'm using a Sony Ericsson C702 (Java Platform 8) as testing server. And a Samsung Galaxy S (ICS 4.0.3, Team ICSSGS RC4.2)

---

**EDIT1**

OK.

I know what the problem is.

I want the JAVAME server to advertise my service with UUID (for example): "68EE1418-12D2-11D7-8EED-00B0D03D76EC", but it seems that the code:

```
        conURL = "btspp://localhost:68EE141812D211D78EED00B0D03D76EC;"
                + "authenticate=false;encrypt=false;name=MySampleApp";
        server = (StreamConnectionNotifier)
                Connector.open(conURL);
```

Adds the default serial port service UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" as a ServiceClassIDList atribute:

[image]

Now, the funny thing is that the Android method BluetoothDevice.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
seems to fetch the default "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" UUID, instead of my "68EE1418-12D2-11D7-8EED-00B0D03D76EC" UUID, overlaping my service with the default Serial Port Service of the mobile phone.

Something similar Medieval Bluetooth Network Scanner, it recognizes my service, but advertised as "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB":

[image]

What could I do to remove that extra `UUID` that `JAVAME` automatically adds to my service?

Please help, thanks!

**EDIT2**

OK, the issue comes with the Sony Ericsson phones. Apparently they insert standard serial port `UUID {0x1101}` ahead of my custom `UUID`, while Samsung and Nokia phones, for example, insert this standard `UUID` behind my own on the service record. Android seems to fetch only the first value of attribute `0x001` on the service record, thus, confuses my service with the default serial port that comes with some devices.

So the solution will be:

Is there any way with current Android API to fetch more `servicerecord` attributes apart from `ServiceClassID (0x001)`?

or

IS there any way to update the `servicerecord` stored on the Service Discovery Database (SDDB) after "acceptAndOpen" -JAVAME- has been called? -I have used `LocalDevice.updateRecord` after service has been created on the `SDDB`, it works on the emulator, but gives an exception and does nothing on actual devices.