# Why does JAVAME switch you bluetooth service's UUID?

Tags: android, service, java-me, bluetooth

In JAVAME when I use this code to advertise my service with UUID "393a84ee7cd111d89527000bdb544cb1" :

```
String connectionURL =
"btspp://localhost:393a84ee7cd111d89527000bdb544cb1;"
+ "authenticate=false;encrypt=false;name=MySampleApp";
```

It gets discovered by other devices with UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".

[image]

This is a HUGE problem for me, as I'm writing an Android application that fetches available services from nearby devices searching for my UUID, but it only discovers the second one, thus being unable of differentiate my service from the default Serial Port service that is present in a lot of phones.

Please help. I'm desperate with this :(.

More information here: [Android bluetooth SDP does not recognize service advertised in JAVAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405575/android-bluetooth-sdp-does-not-recognize-service-advertised-in-javame)